# FastCGI Server C++

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I am developing a server in C++, and I wanted to implement a FastCGI application that goes with it and handles the HTTP requests. I have looked at several examples of applications, but haven't seen anything about what I am supposed to do on the server side in order to communicate with the app.
Could anyone give me some insight on this? I have searched everywhere, even FastCGI website is down.

Comment: Read the CGI specification at https://www.w3.org/CGI/

Comment: Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [fcgid](https://github.com/chenyf/fcgid), a very simple FastCGI Server implementation in C++. It's based on [flup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup/), a fastcgi server written in python.

Additionally, maybe digging into [fastcgipp](https://github.com/eddic/fastcgipp) project can bring you some light. It's a FastCGI Client implementation. There are some good examples of use:

- [HelloWorld](http://isatec.ca/fastcgipp/helloWorld.html)
- [Echo](http://isatec.ca/fastcgipp/echo.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! However, f I may be a bit more specific, I was looking into what needs to be sent as environment variables, and what has to be sent through the stdin from the server to the app.
I have ran an application with nginx to test it out and it worked fine, just wanted to know how to implement on my server.
I'll take a look at what you suggested

Comment: Thats difficult and very error prone. There is a reason why it took more then 15 years before FCGI become somewhat popular. Maybe you should look at other specs like the one the python community is using or rack for the Ruby community.